# Transforming a returned list of strings into interactive outputs

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, user-interface, plotly-dash

I have a search engine that returns an array 'articles' containing an articles.

However I would like to give you a little more Twitter news feed design. I'd also like to be able to click on it and expand them.

Here is the search engine callback:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_search(n_clicks, value):
    f = pickle.load(open("dashboard/data-mm/google-nlu.p", "rb"))
    # let's filter f according to value
    articles = []
    for article in f:
        if value in article['headline']:
            # We want to print this
            articles.append(article)
    print(articles[0])
    return dcc.Markdown([f"{article['headline']}\n" for article in articles])
```

And here's my 'app.py':

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Tabs(
            [
                dcc.Tab(
                    label='Search article',
                    value= 'search',
                    children = article_search() # here handle the potential array
                                                # of articles and put it in form?
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Each black line is a `article['headline']`. Here is `article[0]`:

```
{'headline': 'this is the headline', 
 'body': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting '
         'industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text '
         'ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of '
         'type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has '
         'survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into '
         'electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was '
         'popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets '
         'containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop '
         'publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of '
         'Lorem Ipsum.', 
 'sentiment': -0.4000000059604645, 
 'topics': {'/Finance': 0.6600000262260437}, 
 'topics_kw': ['Politics', 'The financial sector', 'Media', 
               'Society', 'Social projects'], 
 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: This seems like a javascript and styling issue.

Answer (score 2):

**The lazy way of doing this:**

- As far as pushing the data to the app, you could store the values in a `dcc.Store` object (as a json).
- You can then create a callback which formats the information from that json into individual `html objects`.
- Each `html object` could have dynamic callback which changes the `style` attribute of the content so that when a user clicks on it, it does what you'd want.

**The better of doing this:**

- Create your own dash component which contains its own react which will define behaviors similar to the formatting you'd like. *(Warning, unless you're an experienced UX/UI designer it's going to be very difficult to make it look good.)*
- Push your data to a `js` enabled data object – perhaps `window.dataLayer` or something equivalent.
- Write some `js` functions which interact with each dash component to push data from the interactive layer back into your core app.

Sorry I can't be more detailed and descriptive – this is more of schematic response than a solution.